# Erro no webservice: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, web-service, jdbc, delete

Estou tentando executar uma query no meu Webservice, mas a função que a query está dentro de, quebra do nada.

O meu código:

```
public boolean excluir(String usuario)
{
    String sql = "DELETE * FROM listaproduto where uclogin=?";
    Boolean retorno = false;
    PreparedStatement pst = Conexao.getPreparedStatement(sql);
    try {
        pst.setString(1, usuario); //Ele quebra nessa parte.
        if(pst.executeUpdate()>0)
        {
            retorno = true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProdutoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        retorno = false;
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Erro:

> GET SolicitaçãoFailed RequestFailed --> Status: (500) Resposta: { HTTP
>   Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
>   available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.
>   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1
>
> }

Comment: Dá erro ? Se sim edite a pergunta e coloque o erro apresentado

Comment: Pronto já alterei, consegue identificar?

Comment: Qual o retorno de `Conexao.getPreparedStatement(sql);`? Se for nulo, vai falhar na chamada do método `setString()`

Comment: O retorno é o usuário que eu digito, e eu debugo e ele vem o nome de usuário que eu escrevo mesmo, mas ele quebra.

Comment: Me parece que não está vindo um PrepareStatement, está vindo null na chamada ´Conexao.getPreparedStatement(sql)´

Comment: A variavel `usuario` é nula provavelmente, então o problema não é neste trecho de código, mas sim no lugar que chama o excluir.

Comment: Poste o erro que aparece no LOG do glasfish que lhe mostraremos o erro exato.